# Broken upgrade to susy 2.1.2 cannot load such file -- sass/script/node

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

I have just updated to susy 2.1.2 from version 1.0.9 so I expected errors.

However, I have no idea what this means.

I do still have both versions installed:

```
Select gem to uninstall:
 1. susy-1.0.9
 2. susy-2.1.2
 3. All versions
```

When running my `compass:dev` I get the following, although the task still finished. How can I remove the erorrs?

```
Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `each'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `each'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
        from C:/RUBY200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/compass:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

Comment: What version of Compass and Sass are you using?  Have you double checked to make sure they're compatible with the version of Susy you're using?

Comment: Looks like Compass 0.12.2, which is not compatible with Susy 2. You will need to use Compass 1.0 (currently a pre-release) and Sass 3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the message I got when trying to update Susy with bundler.

```
susy (~> 2.1.2) ruby depends on
  sass (~> 3.3.0) ruby

compass (~> 0.12.6) ruby depends on
  sass (3.2.19)
```

This means you will need at least Sass 3.3.0. The latest alpha pre release of Compass will work with this and you can install it with the following command:

```
gem install compass --pre
```

Alternatively if you are using a Gemfile you could install it like this:

```
gem "compass", "~> 1.0.0.alpha.19"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Gemfile need only have these:

```
gem "susy", "~>2.1.0"
gem "sass", "~>3.3.0"
gem "breakpoint", "~>2.4.0"
```

Bundler will sort out the other dependencies (which are many), as well as updating the gems to the latest versions.